# Replacing symbols with spaces in a string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm writing a program that can format text files of thousands of lines of data. The input text file are lines such as:

> 2010-01-01 00:00:00   0.520368    0.558565    0.567376

What I want to do is replace the dashes and ':' with spaces, and then put proper tabs in. I figured out how to fix the tab problem, but my algorithm for replacement just does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated. My code currently looks like this:

```
void getReportInfo(ifstream& file, ofstream& ofile)
{
  string date, time;
  double wheight1, wheight2, wheight3;


         while(!file.eof())
         {
           file >> date >> time >> wheight1 >> wheight2 >> wheight3;

           //replace dashes 
           for(int i = 0; i < date.length(); i++) {
             if(date[i]== '-')
               date[i] == ' ';
           }
           ofile << date << " ";

           //replace colons
           for(int i = 0; i < time.length(); i++) {
             if(time[i]== ':')
               time[i] == ' ';
           }
           ofile << time << " ";

           ofile << "\t" << wheight1 << " \t" << wheight2 << " \t" << wheight3 << endl;
         }
}
```

Comment: Fix this first: [`while(!file.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). After that neither `date[i] == ' ';` nor `time[i] == ' ';` are assigning anything. Those `==` should be `=`, and your compiler should warning you about both of them. If it doesn't, your warning level isn't high enough.

Comment: I can't believe I did that. Thank you! My compiler never gives me warnings which is a problem.
What's wrong with the eof though? I don't know what a better alternative would be to read files of unknown lengths.

Comment: @scrambledeggs read the linked question and answers I provided. It will explain it in detail.

Comment: When this is **done**, do you want *no* spaces in your string *at all*, or do you want the spaces *initially* in the string to be replaced by tabs, then the `-` and `:` replaced with spaces? It makes a difference, and I hope it is clear why.

Comment: @scrambledeggs _"What's wrong with the eof though?"_ Click that link, I've linked it in my answer also.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [`while(!file.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is considered wrong.

> What I want to do is replace the dashes and ':' with spaces, and then put proper tabs in.

If you're really just after replacing `'.'` and `'-'` with `' '` You should have something like

```
 std::string line;
 while(std::getline(file,line)) {
      std::replace(std::begin(line),std::end(line),'-',' ');
      std::replace(std::begin(line),std::end(line),'.',' ');
      ofile << line << std::endl;
 }
```

---

I'm not really sure, what you consider *proper tabs*, but 1st reading to `line`, would serve you well still to parse the particular values you're interested in.
You just parse the wanted values from the `line` using `std::istringstream`:

```
 std::istringstream iss(line);
 iss >> date >> time >> wheight1 >> wheight2 >> wheight3;
```

Comment: There's no `string` member `replace` function that takes those arguments unfortunately. You need to use the standalone `replace` algorithm or use a combination of member `find` and member `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
replace(begin(date), end(date), '-', ' ');
replace(begin(time), end(time), ':', ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11's [`get_time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/get_time/)/[`put_time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/put_time/) actually provides you with an even better solution:

```
tm foo;

while (!file.eof())
{
    file >> get_time(&foo, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> wheight1 >> wheight2 >> wheight3;
    ofile << put_time(&foo, "%Y %m %d %H %M %S") << "\t" << wheight1 << " \t" << wheight2 << " \t" << wheight3 << endl;
}
```

Of course you know from other posts that you need to handle your loop condition better.

Another note is that gcc 4.9.2 does not support `get_time`/`put_time`.

And a final note, the best way to read this in would have been with `get_time(&foo, "%F %T")` however even Microsoft doesn't seem to support that :(

I know that you're probably thinking now that `put_time`/`get_time` are some sketchy backwater solution, but I assure you this *is* kosher C++11.